# If I have an arraylist of labels using mouselistener, how do I get an index when a label is clicked?

Tags: java, graphics, mouselistener

I'm making a card game. It has an arraylist of Jlabels corresponding to each card the player has.

When the card jlabel is clicked, how do I get the index of the individual JLabel, so I can call a playcard() method that plays the card using the given index?

```
JLabel temp = new JLabel(icon);
            temp.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(shift, 550), temp.getPreferredSize()));
            temp.addMouseListener(this);
            currentdeck.add(temp);
//for loop that adds each jlabel to currentdeck
```

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)arg0.getSource();
        //int i = (how would I get the index)?

if(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX()>=label.getX()&&MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY()>=label.getY())
        {
            UNO.playcard(int i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `MouseInfo` like this, `MouseEvent` already passes you the information you need

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to use the `indexOf()` method of ArrayList.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: yes but there can be multiple of the same card in the arraylist, that's the problem

Comment: @Derec Do duplicate cards use the same `JLabel`? If a player has two different copies of the same card then would your code represent both using the same `JLabel` or would you create a distinct `JLabel` for every card object in the game? Because the `JLabel.equals()` method is inherited from `Object`, even if you have two `JLabel` objects with the same text they would not be equal.

Comment: thank you, I think that will work. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @Derec No problem, feel free to ask if you have any other questions